# AttributeError: Python

Tags: python

Hey I am using python script to create ".json" file and getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ngs_rawdata_config_creator.py", line 104, in <module>
    per_lib = parse_per_lib(pd.read_csv(args.per_lib_input, dtype=str))
  File "ngs_rawdata_config_creator.py", line 32, in parse_per_lib
    per_lib_dict['lib_paths'] = assign_libpaths(lib_basepaths)
  File "ngs_rawdata_config_creator.py", line 53, in assign_libpaths
    libpaths_dict[lib] = basepath_to_filepathsdict(path, "*.fastq.gz", ".*_L(\d+)_R(\d+).*\.fastq\.gz")
  File "ngs_rawdata_config_creator.py", line 73, in basepath_to_filepathsdict
    if rmatch.group(0) == basename:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group
```

'

this is the part of the code

```
for fq in all_fastqs:
        basename = os.path.basename(fq)
        rmatch = re.match(capture_regex, basename)
        if rmatch.group(0) == basename:
            lane = rmatch.group(1)
            read = rmatch.group(2)
            readgroups[lane][read] = fq
```

Comment: It tells you the error, `rgroup` is returning `None` and then you are trying to call an attribute on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `re.match` doesn't get a match, it returns `None`. You need to check for that:

```
if rmatch and rmatch.group(0) == basename:
```